# Declaring Variable Outside Foreach Loop in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, foreach

Can someone please enlighten me on the following matter:

```
public class Loopy {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[] myArray = {7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1};

        int counterOne; 
        for (counterOne = 0; counterOne < 5; counterOne++) {
            System.out.println(counterOne + " ");
        }
        System.out.println(counterOne + " ");

        int counterTwo = 0; 
        for (counterTwo : myArray) {
            System.out.println(counterTwo + " ");
        }

    }

}
```

In the for-loop, we declare `counterOne` outside the loop and use it inside the loop. This is correct, so long as we don't use `counterOne` after the loop is completed.

In the foreach-loop, we also declare `counterTwo` outside the loop and then use it **only** inside the loop. However, an error is thrown in this case:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable
>   source code - cannot find symbol   symbol:   class counterTwo   location: class
>   package1.Loopy"

Can you help me understand why?

The only difference between the two, is that `counterOne` is initialized to zero, and then is assigned values incrementally (smaller than 5).

In the foreach loop, `counterTwo` is assigned one by one, each array item.

The program works if we make this adjustment in the second for loop: `for(int counterTwo : myArray)`, while the first for works in both cases:

1. the existing one
2. `for (counterOne = 0; counterOne < 5; counterOne++)`

Comment: I renamed the variables in your code for readability purposes to others who may come across this question (I personally have never tried this and found it interesting).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From [this section of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) about enhanced `for`-loops:

> The enhanced for statement has the form:
>
> *EnhancedForStatement:*
>
> *`for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) Statement`*
>
> *EnhancedForStatementNoShortIf:*
>
> *`for ( {VariableModifier} UnannType VariableDeclaratorId : Expression ) StatementNoShortIf`*

Note that the type declaration ***`UnannType`*** must be present in the `for` loop. Therefore, you should write the loop as follows:

```
for (int z : x) {
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, making it simple, the second one is a "special" for, it's actually a "for each". It always needs the variable declaration inside.
Instead of explaining it badly, here you are the link to an older question about this, check it out:
[Why is declaration of the variable required inside a foreach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136576/why-is-declaration-of-the-variable-required-inside-a-for-each-loop-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

This is just the syntax of a for each loop.  You cannot use a variable defined within the for each loop outside of the loop itself.  It is just how the language is defined.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html